# Finding from the list neg and pos numers in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Two lists of numbers, one with the input pos numbers, and one
with those that are neg numbers (ignore the zero-valued numbers)

Method: You must first build two arrays with the required output numbers, before you
display any of them

the below code is not ruby. how can i convert it to ruby?

```
# Loop to read input and build the two new arrays
while ($next = <>) {
   if ($next > 0) {
      push @pos_list, $next;
   }
   else {
      if ($next < 0) {
         push @neg_list, $next;
      }
   }
}
# Output the results
print "The array of positive numbers: \n @pos_list \n";
print "\nThe array of negative numbers: \n @neg_list \n";
```

Comment: The title and the body are completely unrelated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not an automated Perl to Ruby code conversion service.

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = [4,-2,7,3,0,-8]

pos_list = numbers.select {|x| x > 0}
neg_list = numbers.select {|x| x < 0}

p pos_list # => [4, 7, 3]
p neg_list # => [-2, -8]
```

`numbers` is your array of numbers, which you have built from user input. `Array#select` returns a new array containing all elements that cause the attached block to evaluate to `true`. See: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-select

Comment: You need to explain your reasoning behind the code you provided, help OP understand why it's a proposed solution

Comment: Really? He can't look up [`#select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-select)?

Comment: Yes, it's how stack overflow works. You shouldn't respond with code and not leave at least some explanation. It was brought to my attention for having no accompanying explanation...

Comment: Okay, I didn't realise that was frowned upon, and have seen plenty of other similarly brief answers here. This one seemed fairly self-explanatory to me, but I'll see what I can do to expand upon it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `numbers` to be the array of numbers from the input:

```
pos = []
neg = []
numbers.each do |n|
    pos += n if n > 0
    neg += n if n < 0
end
```

After the above code executes you can retrieve positive numbers from `pos` and negative ones from `neg`.

How you populate `numbers` can vary. A possible solution is too loop and keep asking for a number:

```
numbers = []
begin
    current = gets.chomp.to_i
    numbers << current if current > 0
end until current == 0
```

assuming you don't want `0` to be part of `number`. Otherwise you'll have to check for a given input to stop the loop. Alternatively you can have a fixed size of numbers.

Comment: How can I ask the user to first specify array size then I aske him/her to enter the list of number?

Comment: @user3261528 - That should be asked in another question, but it's not a good question for SO.  SO is not a "write your code for you" service.  Do some reading and experimenting first.  When you get stuck, then ask a question _with what you've tried so far_.